# Compute the condition number of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces, condition-number

Compute the condition number of the matrix $B$ :

$$ B=\begin{bmatrix}3&7&1\\5&8&0\\6&3&2\end{bmatrix} $$ in terms of  $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

*Important*:
Our definition of the condition number:

> Consider a linear map $A : X \rightarrow Y $, then we define the condition number as follows:
>   $$C(A) = \frac{\sup\limits_{x \in X, \|x\|_X=1} \|Ax\|_Y}{\inf\limits_{x \in X, \|x\|_X=1} \|Ax\|_Y}$$ with $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$.

So I've read that if  $A \in \operatorname{isometry}(X,Y)$ then  $C(A) = \|A\|_{L(X,Y)} \|A^{-1}\|_{L(Y,X)}$ with $L(X,Y)$. Do I have to use this? And if I have to use $C(A) = \|A\|_{L(X,Y)} \|A^{-1}\|_{L(Y,X)}$, can you explain what $L(X,Y)$ and $L(Y,X)$ are in this exercise?

Comment: Please type `$3\times 3$` for $3\times 3$ instead of `3 $\times$ 3` for 3 $\times$ 3 because, after all, $3$ ***is*** a mathematical symbol.

Comment: $L(X,Y)$ is the vector space of linear maps from $X$ to $Y$; in this case $X=Y = \mathbb{R}^3$ of course. If $X$ and $Y$ have norms (as is common) then $L(X,Y)$ carries the so-called operator norm, usually: $\|A\|_{L(X,Y)} = \sup \{\{\|Ax\|_Y : x \in X, \|x\|_X = 1 \}$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumAbsoluteColumnSumNorm.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumAbsoluteRowSumNorm.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_Cases

Comment: @JackJ. It is good that you try to improve posts by suggesting edits. However, it would be great if you would make your suggestions more thorough. Take a look at Xander Henderson's [edit here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2836687/revisions) for inspiration.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer♦ Thank you. I will do it!

Answer (score 2):

Let us compute for the $L^1$-norm. All "modules" applied on a vector
$$ x=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} \ne 0$$
reflect the $1$-norm for a while.

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sup_{|x|=1}|Bx|
&=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|Bx|}{|x|}
\\
&=\sup_{(a,b,c)\ne 0}\frac{|3a+7b+c|+|5a+8b|+|6a+3b+2c|}{|a|+|b|+|c|}
\\
&\le
\sup_{(a,b,c)\ne 0}
\frac
{3|a|+7|b|+|c|+5|a|+8|b|+6|a|+3|b|+2|c|}
{|a|+|b|+|c|}
\\
&=
\sup_{(a,b,c)\ne 0}
\frac
{14|a|+18|b|+3|c|}
{|a|+|b|+|c|}
\\
\\
&\le
\sup_{(a,b,c)\ne 0}
\frac
{18|a|+18|b|+18|c|}
{|a|+|b|+|c|}
\\
&=18\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the value $18$ is taken for $(0,1,0)$. 
Note that we are taking the maximal value for the sum of the modules of the column entries of the given matrix, this is the second column, the result is $\max(3+5+6, \ 7+8+3,\ 1+0+2)=18$. 
For the infimum... Let $C$ be the matrix
$$
C =
B^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}3&7&1\\5&8&0\\6&3&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\frac 1{55}
\begin{bmatrix}
-16 & 11 & 8 \\
10 & 0 & -5 \\
33 & -33 & 11
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Then
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\inf_{|x|=1}|Bx|
&=\inf_{x\ne 0}\frac{|Bx|}{|x|}
\\
&\qquad\text{Substitution: $Bx=y$...}
\\
&=\inf_{y\ne 0}\frac{|y|}{|Cy|}
\\
&=\left(\sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{|Cy|}{|y|}\right)^{-1}
\\
&=\left(\max\
\left(\ 
\frac 1{55}(16+10+33),\ 
\frac 1{55}(11+0+33),\ 
\frac 1{55}(8+5+11),\ 
\right)\ 
\right)^{-1}
\\
&=\left(\frac{59}{55}\right)^{-1}
=\frac{55}{59}\approx 0.932203389830508\dots
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have only to take the quotient now,
$$
C(B)=\frac{18}{55/59}=
\frac {1065}{55}\approx 19.3090909090\dots\ .
$$

---

Same game for the $\infty$-norm.
All "modules" on a non-zero vector are denoting in the following this norm.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sup_{|x|=1}|Bx|
&=\sup_{\substack{x=(a,b,c)^T\\|a|,|b|,|c|\le 1}}|Bx|
\\
&=\sup_{|a|,|b|,|c|\le 1}\max(\ |3a+7b+c|,\ |5a+8b|,\ |6a+3b+2c|\ )
\\
&\le
\sup_{|a|,|b|,|c|\le 1}\max(\ 3+7+1,\ 5+8,\ 6+3+2\ )
\\
&=\max(\ 3+7+1,\ 5+8,\ 6+3+2\ )=13\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This time we are taking the maximal value of the sums of the absolute values on the rows. The second row won. The maximum is taken for $a=b=c=1$.

For the infimum value, we pass again to $C=B^{-1}$, the corresponding supremum is
$\frac 1{55}(33+33+11)=\frac 15(3+3+1)=\frac 75$, so the infimum needed for $B$ is its inverse, 
$$\frac 57\approx 0.\,714285\,714285\dots\ $$
So
$$
C(B) = \frac{13}{5/7}=\frac{91}5=18.2
\ .
$$

---

Computer simulation. This experience should not be underestimated. It is often important to be able to check in a second such results. Here using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

Code:

```
import random
sup1, inf1, supoo, infoo = 0, oo, 0, oo    # init, we will make some of them bigger, the other smaller...

n1  = lambda  a,b,c:         abs(a) + abs(b) + abs(c)
noo = lambda  a,b,c:    max( abs(a) , abs(b) , abs(c) )

B = matrix(QQ, 3, 3, [3,7,1, 5,8,0, 6,3,2] )

for trial in xrange(10**6):
    a, b, c = [ random.uniform(-1,1) for _ in (1,2,3) ]
    s, t, u = B*vector( [a,b,c] )

    norm1 = n1( s,t,u ) / n1( a,b,c )
    if norm1 > sup1:    sup1 = norm1
    if norm1 < inf1:    inf1 = norm1

    normoo = noo( s,t,u ) / noo( a,b,c )
    if normoo > supoo:    supoo = normoo
    if normoo < infoo:    infoo = normoo

print "1-norm:", sup1, inf1, sup1/inf1
print "oo-norm:", supoo, infoo, supoo/infoo
```

Results this time:

```
1-norm: 17.9935919413 0.936889759239 19.2056661564
oo-norm: 12.9999942319 0.716228500506 18.1506240295
```

Comment: Thanks, i am correcting it!